# Como asignar una variable leída de un archivo de conf .INI sólo 1 vez

Tags: linux, bash, configuración

He estado mirando sobre como asignar los valores leídos de un archivo de configuración .ini a las variables de mi script y que solo se asignen (carguen los valores necesarios) una vez al arrancar el archivo.
He probado usando awk y sed , pero lo que consigo es que se este leyendo continuamente la variable y asignandola cada vez que se requiera el valor de la misma.

y el script que lee es este (aqui uso una funcion pero no me sirve su resultado (usando sed)):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Archivo de configuacion
archivo_conf=config.ini

function read_ini()
{
    local KEY="$1"
    local FILE="$2"
    awk -F "=" '/'"$KEY"'/ {print $2}' "$FILE"
}



while true; 
 do


if [ $tiempo1 -ge $tiempoMax ] || [ $tiempo -ge $tiempoMax ]; then
//....
fi

done
```

Aparte de que no se almacena solo una vez y que se carga constantemente obtengo esto en la salida de forma continua cada vez que se comprueba usando el valor de la variable :

```
: integer expression expected 20
: integer expression expected 20
```

PD: Como mucho en el archivo .INI habria unas 20 variables

**EDICION EN BASE A LA RESPUESTA DE @fedorqui**

mi_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#Incorporacion de las variables del archivo de conf
. config.ini

#Contadores
tiempo1=0
tiempo=0


while true; 
 do


if [ $tiempo1 -ge $ping_op_max ] || [ $tiempo -ge $ping_op_max ]; then

//....
fi
done
```

Obtengo el error :

```
: integer expression expected 20
: integer expression expected 20
```

cada vez que pasa por ese if.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si todo lo que contiene tu fichero de configuración son variables que quieres usar, ¿por qué no incorporarlo directamente con [`source`](https://superuser.com/a/46146/204979)?

Sea el fichero de configuración:

```
hola=23
adios=45
```

Y el script algo así como:

```
$ cat mi_script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

. conf.ini  # <---- esto ejecuta el fichero `conf.ini` realizando las asignaciones

echo "$hola"
```

Cuando lo ejecutamos tenemos las variables ya a disposición:

```
$ ./mi_script.sh.sh 
23
```

Comment: ¡Que simple y elegante!

Comment: sigo obteniendo este errror , ```: integer expression expected 20
: integer expression expected 20``` cada vez que se utilizar el valor de la variable

Comment: @Shockz parece como que estés proporcionando un valor no numérico. Revisa tu fichero de configuración y edita la pregunta si hay algún dato relevante a tener en cuenta. Puedo replicar el error con por ejemplo `[ "a 3" -eq 3 ] && echo "yes"`.

Comment: el archivo de configuracion, es similar y con la misma estructura que el que proporcione , la variables solo tienen "integers" (valores numericos) , y cuando utilizo la variable para comprar utilizo el operador ```ge``` y se este se comprar con otro valor numerico (tipo integer) , es mas la unicalinea en la que uso la concreta variable que extraigo del archivo de conf, es la que figura en mi pregunta

Comment: ah , una cosa no importa que haya mas variables locales definidas por debajo de la linea donde se ejecuta el ```source``` no?

Comment: @Shockz yo lo que veo es que usas `$tiempoObjetivo`, `$tiempoMax` y `$tiempoPLC` pero solo defines la primera de las variables. De ahí que el `if [ ]` falle, porque se encuentra con partes de la comparación vacías (véase por ejemplo lo que da si haces `[ -eq 2 ] && echo "yes"`). Y sí, `source` puede usarse y después definir otras variables.

Comment: obvie esa informacion por que no la vi relevante con mi pregunta , voy a editar mi pregunta para proporcionarte el codigo segun tu respuesta y asi me puedas ayudar mejor

Comment: Gracias! He probado tu código y me funciona bien, no puedo reproducir el error. ¿Será que el fichero de configuración tiene caracteres raros?

Comment: no, la verdad, fue hecho a mano.... pues ahora si que estoy confuso, a ver , he hecho un mini script de comprobacion , y claro si utilizco ```echo "$ping_op_max"``` lo imprime correctamente pero al parecer al estar en ese if , va mal...

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner el if antes del while? Lo mismo el problema está en cómo modificas el valor de `$tiempoObjetivo` y `$tiempoPLC` dentro del bucle.

Comment: por temas de privacidad te voy a mandar un correo ahroa mismo con el contenido de mi script completo, vale? segun tu perfil seria , fedorqui.se@gmail.com, si no estas deacuerdo, seguimos por aqui

Comment: @Shockz no entiendo qué ocurre, todo parece correcto pero por algún motivo no considera numérico lo que se le pasa. Parece que todo es por culpa de `$ping_op_max`...

Comment: joder, acabo de borrar y escribir de nuevo todo el archivo... y ahora ya no obtengo error... pues no habia espacios ni nada donde pudiera haber algún caracter oculto ... *sigh* , gracias por todo creo que asi me sirve ya , como ultima pregunta, con este metodo del source solo se cargan esos valores al arranque del archivo , si ahora cambio el valor de una variable en el config.ini , tendria que reiniciar mi script , correcto?

Comment: @Shockz ¿será que se coló algún carácter? Yo probé haciendo `cat -vet fichero.ini` y ver si salía algún carácter raro y a simple vista no lo había. Pero claramente era algo así. Bueno, mejor si era eso :D

Comment: @Shockz respecto lo de `source`, sí: se ejecuta cuando el script pasa por la línea que lo llama. Si quieres recargar las variables, debes volver a ejecutarlo con `.` o `source`.

Answer (score 3):

### Resumen

Se me ocurren dos ideas:

1. Revisar si la variable tiene algo asignado
2. Declarar la variable de solo lectura.

### Revisar la variable

Si quieres que una variable se asigne sólo una vez, se me ocurre que primero revises si esa variable tiene contenido.

En caso de no tenerlo, entonces procedes a asignar, de lo contrario, continuar normal el flujo del programa.

En otras palabras:

```
$ [[ -z ${variable} ]] && echo "No existe o tiene tamaño cero"
```

Que en tu caso espefíco, sería:

```
$ [[ -z ${tiempoMax} ]] && tiempoMax=$(read_ini "ping_op_max" "$archivo_conf")
```

Esto suponiendo que la variable está cambiando constantemente. En caso de no ser así, y de querer que esta sea persistente, mejor sería que la almacenaras en algun archivo temporal.

Además, en el caso de one-line con `awk`, te sugiero que mejor uses esto, ya que —al menos para mi— es más claro:

```
$ awk -F "=" '$1 == "ping_op_max"{print $2}' archivo.ini
```

### Declarándola como únicamenta para lectura

En bash (y creo que en otras shells), se puede hacer esto con el parámetro `-r` del builtin `declare`. Es decir:

```
$ declare -r var1="esto solo se escribirá una vez"
```

De esta manera, en tu código quedaría:

```
declare -r tiempoMax=$(read_ini "ping_op_max" "$archivo_conf")
```

Si en otro lado (bucle, otro código cargado, en otra sección) se quisiera volver a asignar esa variable, entonces recibirías un error de la forma:

```
bash: var1: readonly variable
```

En ese caso, ese error diría que todo fue "bien". Entonces podrías eliminar los mensajes de error redirigiéndolos a `/dev/null`.

### Nota

A pesar de mis sugerencias dadas, te recomendaría que tratarás de cambiar tu código para evitar este tipo de workarounds y dejar todo más claro para el que edite el código, y en si para que la lógica sea más fluida.

Comment: obtengo el error ```./modulo_ping.sh: line 50: [: 12: unary operator expected
./modulo_ping.sh: line 50: [: 0: unary operator expected
``` en la linea donde se utiliza el valor de esa variable "tiempoMax" para compararla con otra

Comment: @Shockz, eso no tiene que ver con tu pregunta inicial, sino con un error en la escritura de tu condicional. Trata de tener cada cosa separada por espacios; es decir: `if [ <condicion> ]`. Para Bash, son fundamentales los espacios más que los otros caracteres.

Comment: Mira, de hecho escribí un artículo sobre eso: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/conditional-expressions-shell-script#a-quick-note-about-spaces
Busca hasta el final, sobre los espacios.

Comment: el problema no era si definia o no bien el if , al final fue algo que no entendi como paso, pero mi archivo de configuracion contenia caracteres extraños ocultos. Lo averigue borrandolo y escribiendo todo de nuevo, seguido a eso , todo funciono

Comment: @Shockz, no es necesario hacer eso. Puedes utilizar `cat -A <archivo>` para ver los caracteres ocultos. A veces vim o nano te pueden ayudar. En este sitio hay respuestas similares, por si gustas darles un vistaso.

Comment: gracias me sera de utilidad ese comando para comprobar mis scripts